# Finding lim sup and lim inf of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $x_1=\frac13,x_{2n}=\frac13x_{2n-1},x_{2n+1}=\frac13+x_{2n}$ where $n\in \mathbb N.$

Explicitly, this sequence is $\frac13,\frac19,\frac49,\frac4{27},\frac{13}{27},\frac{13}{81},\dots$

How to find its lim sup and lim inf?

I think lim sup $=\frac12$ and lim inf $=\frac19$ Is this correct?  However, I do not know how to prove.

Comment: Hint: Use the recurence formulas to show that $x_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}x_{2n-1}$ or with $a_{n} = x_{2n+1}$ this becomes $a_n = \frac{1+a_{n-1}}{3}$. Do the same thing for $b_n = x_{2n}$ to show that $b_n = \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{3}b_{n-1}$. You can now solve for $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to prove by induction that
$$ x_{2n+1} = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2\cdot 3^{n+1}},\qquad x_{2n}= \frac{3^{n}-1}{2\cdot 3^{n+1}}$$
hence $\limsup=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\liminf=\frac{1}{6}$.